# What is the derivative of $\frac{\ln x}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My equation is the following.

$$\dfrac{\ln x}{x} = 0.28$$

I think I can solve it with derivation, but I can't compute the derivative of $\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Why do you need to take derivative of that function if you want to solve for $x$ for the following equation $\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x} = 0.28$?  You should know that the derivative of the function determines the rate of the function.

Comment: Some words of advice: Rearrange the terms to obtain the expression like the form $z = W(z)e^{W(z)}$.  Then, use Lambert W-function.

Comment: If you're in a calculus class, you probably don't know what the Lambert W-function is. Do you know Newton's method? The solutions all involve the Lambert W-function; you probably want to approximate your solutions. What exactly is the context of this question?

Comment: actually I don't know nearly anything about math, my girl friend asked me and I couldn't say I don't know:) So I've asked you I just need solution to tell her :)

Comment: Ok, according to @Dmoreno's solution offers, I understand I won't manage this and I will tell to my gf, I couldn't do it. Thanks all guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the derivative of such a function you may use the product rule for derivatives:

$$(fg)' = f'g+fg'.$$

Thus, identifying $f=\ln{x}$ and $g = 1/x$, you have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln{x}}{x} = \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{x}  - \ln{x} \frac{1}{x^2} = (\ln{x}-1)/x^2.$$

However, I can't see how this could help you to solve your equation. Furthermore, your equation,

$$\ln{x} = k \, x \ \Leftrightarrow \ x = e^{kx},$$

is said to be a trascendental equation and need the help of the Lambert $W$ function  (or plotting, or numerical approach, etc) to be solved.

Cheers!

Comment: You right it didn't help me :) how can i solve the equation ?

Comment: Hi there @Mustafa. You cannot solve it analytically. You can try different approaches like: a) Plotting the function $f(x) = x-e^{kx}$ and search for a zero of $f$, b) Proceed numerically and solve $f(x) = 0$ by using, for example, Newton-Raphson method, c) Learn more about the Lambert W function or product logarithm function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. I hope this is useful to you!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of equations cannot be solved using elemental functions. Consider the function log(x)/x - 0.28 or simpler log(x) - 0.28 x (this will be easier for derivatives). If you analyse the derivative, you could notice that it is positive for 0 < x < 1 / 0.28, zero at x = 1 / 0.28 and then negative. The second derivative test shows that x = 1 / 0.28 corresponds to a maximum and the function value is positive. So, you have two roots  . If you plot the function, you will see that the function cancels close to 1.5 and 7.0.

Suppose that you do have any access to Lambert function. Then, use Newton method starting from a guess (name it x_old) which is updated according to

x_new = x_old - F(x_old) / F'(x_old)

Replace x_old by x_new and repeat until you reach the accuracy you want.

For illustration puroposes, I shall be very lazzy and start at x_old = 1. Applying Newton scheme, the successive iterates are : 1.38889, 1.52613, 1.53834, 1.53842. For this last value of x, the value of the function is -1.56438*10^-9.

Repeat the exercise starting at x=7.0 to refine the second root.

Comment: Very good pints. They ,all, complete the solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

The only think you could check only by using derivatives is whether this function has a real solution.

To do that, consider your $f(x)=\frac{\log x}x-0.28$ and find a point of minimum $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$, (and $f''(x_0)>0$). Now take this $x_0$ and plug into $f$. If $f(x_0)>0$, i.e., if the minimum of the function is greater than $0$, your equality won't have any real solution.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two roots. The diagram I attached show where the zeros are.

[image: zeros of the function]

The zeros are:

$x\approx 1.53842$ and $x\approx 6.89646$